# How to store value of SqlDataReader in a list<class>?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

Hi I have a method which returns list but i'm getting un-desired results,please let me know what is wrong in below code.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "select * from Blogs order by id desc"; 
SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader(); 
List<Blogs> blogslist = new List<Blogs>(); 
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
   blog.Id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["id"]); 
   blog.email = reader["email"].ToString(); 
   blog.description = reader["description"].ToString(); 
   blog.date =Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]); 
   blogslist.Add(blog); 
}
```

Comment: What is the undesired result ? Error message What is it ? Wrong results ? What is it ? Empty list ? Wrong data in a specific column. Please update your answer and be specific.

Comment: Blogs table has 4 different records , after reader.read() the blogslist contains the same record 4 times instead of 4 different records .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blog has been declared & instantiated outside of your reader.Read() statement, you are updating the same object reference each time around the loop which is why you are seeing repeating objects in your list.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "select * from Blogs order by id desc"; 
SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader(); 
List<Blogs> blogslist = new List<Blogs>(); 
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
   var blog = new Blogs();
   blog.Id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["id"]); 
   blog.email = reader["email"].ToString(); 
   blog.description = reader["description"].ToString(); 
   blog.date =Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]); 
   blogslist.Add(blog); 
}
```

Please mark this as your accepted answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: He posted the code as plain text at first, that's what the <classType> part got removed somehow.

Comment: Thanks user3185569, that eliminates that part then.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael :-)